# Background image via CSS in ASP.NET Core 5.0

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-core

I have an issue, i need to set background images of different elemtns in Razor template via css file, the structure of the project is:

[Project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FstGk.png)

I'm trying to add bg image to the class "search-div" in the file, the code is below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Интернет-магазин RTX</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/script.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <nav class="clearfix">
            <ul class="clearfix">
                <li><a href="#">ГЛАВНАЯ</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">КОРЗИНА</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">ВОЙТИ</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">РЕГИСТРАЦИЯ</a></li>
            </ul>
            <a href="#" id="pull">МЕНЮ</a>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class='outer_search'></div>
        <div class='search_div'>
            <form id='search' action="">
                <input id='searchline' type="search" placeholder="Поиск товара...">
                <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    @RenderBody()
    <script src="~/js/select_menu.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm getting the problem that the image is not visible on site, but the images from my models are displayed correctly (images in other file from renderbody()), so how can i fix this problem?
Css file:

```
.outer_search {
    position: absolute;
    height: 300px;
    width: 100%;
    background: url('../images/main.jpg');
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    filter: blur(5px);
    -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
}
```

In addition i can say that all styles are working correctly

Comment: open the browser's inspector tool and locate your CSS style tab, try clicking the image link (or hovering should show the image as well). If it shows correctly, your element may be out of screen or invisible for some reason. There are many reasons for an image to not show when it involves the client environment. The server is just responsible for rendering the HTML.

Comment: This image is displayed correctly on proper html+css project. I noticed this things, maybe it can help to understand what is the reason: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ao3b8.png
The actual path is images/main.jpg but it displayed like css/main.jpg

Comment: that's your assumption, just follow the steps I've suggested to confirm its actual URL. The url in CSS should be relative to the root `/images` but you include `..`

Comment: It seems like  background: url('../images/main.jpg') should use /images/ from /css/, but instead of it in any way it's pointing to /css/main.jpg

Comment: the browser does not have that feature because it does not know about the directories on the server side. Actually `/images/main.jpg` works but `../images/main.jpg` should work as well (just tested it). It's strange that the URL is rendered as just `main.jpg` on your side, that's why it does not work. Try clearing the cache on your browser, or try a new browser instead.

Comment: From your description, I assume the `.outer_search` class is in the style.css file. I tried to create a sample using `../images/main.jpg`, it seems that it works well on my side, check this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/upKmM.png). So, as King said, perhaps the issue relates the browser cache, try to clear the browser cache.

Answer (score 0):

The way you can add the image is to set the path like (/images/image.png) and not (../image/image.png). Although the path in the browser will be displayed like this below, but it will work.
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6nZG.png)